# Как сделать чтобы следующий после Application.launch(args); код выполнился без закрытия окна?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть окно написанное используя javaFX. Я запускаю его с пом. `Application.launch(args);`. И следующие строки кода выполнятся только после закрытия javaFX окна. Можно сделать так, чтобы код выполнялся сразу, без закрытия окна?

```
public class Clock extends Application implements Runnable {

public synchronized void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new StackPane();
    Label label = new Label(showTime());
    label.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 45));
    pane.getChildren().add(label);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane,200, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("TIME");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    if(primaryStage.isMaximized())
        System.exit(2);

}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    boolean stop = false;

    while(!stop){
        System.out.println(showTime());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
}

private String showTime() {
    Date dt = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    return formatDate.format(dt);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clock digitalClock = new Clock();
    Application.launch(args);
    digitalClock.run();
}
```

Comment: выполнить код в новом потоке

Comment: Не совсем понял. Как раз у меня после Application.launch() идет clock.start.
(В классе Clock метод run)

Comment: я думаю Вам не сделать, так, как вы хотите.  Application.launch() скорее всего блокирующий и поэтому Clock нужно запускать уже из него или до него

Comment: было бы больше информации, что делает Clock, передает ли данные в gui, тогда можно было бы что-то посоветовать

Comment: @alex вообще, я хочу с помощью потока сделать часы. Т.е. сначала запускается gui, а потом поток с пом. while(true){sleep(1000);...} выводил каждую секунду время в gui. Правда я пока не разобрался, как перерисовывать gui. Примерный набросок добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам просто покажу как оно будет работать, но весь код надо переписывать. private static label - это костыль в данном случае. Не надо делать универсальный класс. Вынесите Runnable в отдельный класс, иначе запутаетесь. 
И непосредственный вызов run() выполняет задачу в текущем потоке. Правильно new Thread(runnable).start. 
Platform.runLater - это один из способов воздействия на gui. Можно по-другому.

```
public class Clock extends Application implements Runnable {
private static Label label;

public synchronized void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new StackPane();
    label = new Label(showTime());
    label.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 45));
    pane.getChildren().add(label);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("TIME");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    new Thread(new Clock()).start();

    if (primaryStage.isMaximized())
        System.exit(2);

}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    boolean stop = false;

    while (!stop) {
        Platform.runLater(()->{updateTimer(showTime());});
        //System.out.println(showTime());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}

public void updateTimer(String time){
    label.setText(time);
}

private String showTime() {
    Date dt = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    return formatDate.format(dt);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);

}
```

}

Comment: А почему private static label - костыль?

Comment: P.S. Кажется понял. Вы объявили ее стат. полем, что бы ее можно было использовать вне start()?

Comment: я вызываю updateTimer из второстепенного потока, и если Label сделать не статическим, то придется втор. потоку давать ссылку на начальный класс, иначе он будет дергать свою Label, а она у него равна null. Ну просто так быстрее было.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.